# Where is my Java script code in android apk in case of react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, apk

Since last two month I am working on first `react-native` application. As per the documentation `react-native` runs the java script code in a virtual dom. But when I extract my apk, there is not a single file of java script. So I am little confused here that how this whole thing works? If any one have any idea please example me.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Raptor though he want to re-skin another RN APK xD

Comment: @Raptor I just wanted to know where is all my code in apk. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Source files will not be compiled in APK in plain text. That's what a compiler is for.

Comment: I think @FaisalKhan wonders when js components are converted native components.

Answer (score 8):

All javascript is bundled into a file called `index.android.bundle` or on ios it is `index.ios.bundle`

[image]

Comment: I can see any index.android.bundle file in debug apk

Comment: By default, It doesn't build a bundle for debug version. The packager serves it from the Dev server. For live reloading, debugging etc

Comment: ok is it possible to see it's content. As per reactNative documentation, it converts code to native components but in this file I can see only HTML kind of content

Comment: Not exactly. There is more detail to it. It doesn't convert to native components in this file. It is still javascript code . The communication happens on the react-native bridge and native components gets created/destroyed/managed according to the UI

Comment: Thanks, can you help me by sharing some link having such kind of details which helps in understanding react-native platform in deep

Comment: Probably this one https://www.reactnative.guide/3-react-native-internals/3.1-react-native-internals.html,  and reading react native github source code/issues

Answer (score -1):

Basically it renders the parent JS component file using FacebookReactNative library and this library takes care of rendering the JS.

In the MainActivity, it is written as -

```
 @Override
protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "abc";
}
```

This tells the parent of JS component.